# PyQt QDialog return response yes or no

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a QDialog class

```
confirmation_dialog = uic.loadUiType("ui\\confirmation_dialog.ui")[0]

class ConfirmationDialog(QDialog,confirmation_dialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        message = "Hello, Dialog test"
        self.yes_button.clicked.connect(self.yes_clicked)
        self.no_button.clicked.connect(self.no_clicked)
        self.message_box.insertPlainText(message)

    def yes_clicked(self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("dialog_response"),"yes")

    def no_clicked(self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("dialog_response"),"no")
```

I have a function which requires confirmation to continue or not, but with the current implementation it doesn't wait for `QDialog` to close.

How can I make my function wait for response from `QDialog` and then proceed accordingly.

I want to implement something similar to `confirm` function as shown below

```
def function(self):
    ....
    ....
    if self.confirm() == 'yes':
        #do something
    elif self.confirm() == 'no':
        #do something

def confirm(self):
    dialog = ConfirmationDialog()
    dialog.show()
    return #response from dialog
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use `dialog.exec_()`, which will open the dialog in a modal, blocking mode and returns an integer that indicates whether the dialog was accepted or not.  Generally, instead of emitting signals, you probably just want to call `self.accept()` or `self.reject()` inside the dialog to close it.

```
dialog = ConfirmationDialog()
result = dialog.exec_()
if result:  # accepted
    return 'accepted'
```

If I'm using a dialog to get a specific set of values from the user, I'll usually wrap it in a `staticmethod`, that way I can just call it and get values back within the control flow of my application, just like a normal function.

```
class MyDialog(...)

    def getValues(self):
        return (self.textedit.text(), self.combobox.currentText())

    @staticmethod
    def launch(parent):
        dlg = MyDialog(parent)
        r = dlg.exec_()
        if r:
            return dlg.getValues()
        return None

values = MyDialog.launch(None)
```

However, in almost all cases where I just need to present a message to the user, or get them to make a choice by clicking a button, or I need them to input a small piece of data, I can use the built-in static methods on the normal dialog classes -- [`QMessageBox`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html#question), [`QInputDialog`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qinputdialog.html#getText)